# Faster way to generate a sequence of numbers

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, integer-sequence

There is a sequence of Numbers that satisfies

(1) $a_1+p\geq 0, a_2+p=0, p\in R$
(2) $a_{4n}>a_{4 n-1}, (n=1,2,...)$
(3) $a_{m+n}\in\{a_m+a_n+p, a_m+a_n+p+1\}, (m,n=1,2...)$

I tried to list the first `k` items using the code below,

```
k = 6;
eqn = Table[And@@Function[{m,n},And[a[1]+p>=0,a[2]==-p,a[4]>a[3],a[8]>a[7],
 a[m+n]==a[m]+a[n]+p||a[m+n]==a[m]+a[n]+p+1]]@@@IntegerPartitions[i,{2}],{i,2,k}]
Solve[eqn,Array[a,k],Reals]//Normal
```

> {{a[1]->-p,a[2]->-p,a[3]->-p,a[4]->1-p,a[5]->1-p,a[6]->1-p}}

When I set `k` to be greater than 6, it has been running for a long time. Do you have a faster way to generate more terms of this sequence?

Comment: Is there a condition for p? If a_n were defined succesfully upto k, (I mean upto k, the sequence a_n satisfies (1),(2),(3)), can we always find a suitable value for a_(k+1) that satisfies (1),(2),(3) ? The second question is about mathematics.

Comment: Your main purpose is solving/attacking mathematical problem for a_n, using mathematica?

Comment: @imidak `p` is a real number. I need to list more, try to find patterns.

Comment: I just ran the case for `k=6`, and it took 2.5 seconds, yielding `{a[1] -> -p, a[2] -> -p, a[3] -> -p, a[4] -> 1 - p, a[5] -> 1 - p, 
 a[6] -> 1 - p}`, but `k=7` is taking much longer.

Comment: Based on the first few cases (`k=2` through `k=6`), it sure seems like every such sequence consists of a bunch of `-p`'s followed by one or more `1-p`'s. If there's a good reason to believe that this continues to hold, it might be faster to just *check* each such sequence to see if it satisfies the conditions, provided that `k` doesn't need to be too large.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one suggestion that might work.  It seems (on a cursory glance of the conditions making up the sequence) that previous solutions are nested in current ones.  For that reason, it probably makes sense to define this recursively.  Below, I have worked out a klugey solution based on your current code.  It could be made much nicer, but I believe that it works. Part of the kluge is in the following, where in order to make the solutions work, I need to get rid of the conditions `a[4] > a[3]` and `a[8] > a[7]` when they are unnecessary:

```
generateConditions[k_ /; 2 <= k <= 3] := 
 Table[And @@ 
   Function[{m, n}, 
     And[a[1] + p >= 0, a[2] == -p, 
      a[m + n] == a[m] + a[n] + p || 
       a[m + n] == a[m] + a[n] + p + 1]] @@@ 
    IntegerPartitions[i, {2}], {i, 2, k}]
generateConditions[k_ /; 4 <= k <= 7] := 
 Table[And @@ 
   Function[{m, n}, 
     And[a[1] + p >= 0, a[2] == -p, a[4] > a[3], 
      a[m + n] == a[m] + a[n] + p || 
       a[m + n] == a[m] + a[n] + p + 1]] @@@ 
    IntegerPartitions[i, {2}], {i, 2, k}]
generateConditions[k_ /; 8 <= k] := 
 Table[And @@ 
   Function[{m, n}, 
     And[a[1] + p >= 0, a[2] == -p, a[4] > a[3], a[8] > a[7], 
      a[m + n] == a[m] + a[n] + p || 
       a[m + n] == a[m] + a[n] + p + 1]] @@@ 
    IntegerPartitions[i, {2}], {i, 2, k}]
```

Then, the solutions are recursively defined with the `k = 2` case as the base case:

```
ClearAll@generateSolutions
generateSolutions[2] = Solve[generateConditions[2], Array[a, 2], Reals]

generateSolutions[k_ /; k > 2] := generateSolutions[k] = Module[
   {sols, solOld = generateSolutions[k - 1]}
   , sols = Table[
     Join[sol, #] & /@ 
      Solve[generateConditions[k] /. sol // DeleteDuplicates // 
        Simplify, a[k], Reals]
     , {sol, solOld}]
   ; Cases[sols, {__, a[k] -> _}, Infinity]
   ]
```

You can run the code to get the following, very quickly. (The `k = 7` case is the second one to generate two solutions, and it takes a very long time to solve with the original case, which is why I started there.)

```
generateSolutions[7]
(* {{a[1] -> -p, a[2] -> -p, a[3] -> -p, a[4] -> 1 - p, a[5] -> 1 - p, a[6] -> 1 - p, a[7] -> 1 - p},
    {a[1] -> -p, a[2] -> -p, a[3] -> -p, a[4] -> 1 - p, a[5] -> 1 - p, a[6] -> 1 - p, a[7] -> 2 - p}} *)
```

and

```
generateSolutions[8]
(* {{a[1] -> -p, a[2] -> -p, a[3] -> -p, a[4] -> 1 - p, a[5] -> 1 - p, a[6] -> 1 - p, a[7] -> 1 - p, a[8] -> 2 - p}} *)
```